Using Time::HiRes in project after downloading from online: HiRes.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr
I just started my hands on with Perl last week, because I was made to fix few things in our legacy code in production.
Situation is, there is perl 5.32.0 installed in our production and I can't change or install any packages in it.
In my code, I have to get time in milliseconds, which can be fetched using Time::HiRes module.
But, I can't install it!
So, I copied it in my project alongside my project file.
I downloaded Time-HiRes-1.9764.tar.gz from https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes, unzipped it and copied HiRes.pm under Time directory under my project.
I am getting this error:
/usr/local/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/bin/perl_5.6.1/lib/site_perl/5.6.1/i686-linux/auto/Time/HiRes/HiRes.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr

Now, my questions is:
What is the correct way of downloading HiRes.pm from online and copy in local project without any dependency?
2. List item

Time::HiRes should already be installed. It is part of Perl core installation since v5.7.3. Are you sure it is not installed? What do you get if you type perldoc -l Time::HiRes?

You keep insisting you can't install it, but you then you say you (badly) installed it. Why do you say you can't install it? Is it because you think you have insufficient system permissions? You can install modules into any directory. You just did it wrong. If that's the issue, we can show you how.

@TLP : $ /usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.32.0/bin/perldoc -l "Time::HiRes"
/usr/local/packages/perl_remote/5.32.0/bin/perldoc: Command not found.
I don't have permission to run perldoc. perldoc is present in the directory.

@ikegami: Yes, I don't have permissions. Also, this production environment is not connected to internet, hence I can't install.
Anyway, I did work around by fetching millisecond using date +%s.%N

As mentioned, in the comment that brought up qx{ date +%s.%N }, it makes no sense to use it since it takes a good chunk of a second if not an entire second to use. You'd get a more precise result from time.

@OmSao You don't have permission to run perldoc? That's literally just an information command. Your installation seems to be broken, you should contact the server admin and ask them to fix it. It seems they have changed permissions on some core features of Perl. That is your solution. Also, perlbrew can install modules in your own users files.


Time::HiRes has been a core module since 5.7.3, i.e. it should be part of the Perl installation.

The standard way of installing a Perl module is


perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install

Some Perl modules aren't pure Perl, they also contain XS code that needs to be compiled, and Time::HiRes is one of them.

Thank @choroba. Unfortunately, I can't install in production perl.
Is there any other way, I can get the epoch time in millisecons without Time::HiRes?
Any workaround?

You can probably do qx{ date +%H:%M:%S.%N }, but it will be so slow there won't be any point to measure milliseconds. My benchmark shows it's several thousand times slower than using Time::HiRes.

You need neither internet nor permissions.
First, get the tarball onto the machine and unzip and extract the files.
Then, use the INSTALL_BASE parameter to tell the installer where to install it.
tar xzf Time-HiRes-1.9764.tar.gz
cd Time-HiRes-1.9764
perl MakeFile.PL INSTALL_BASE=...
make test
make install

Finally, make sure to set env var PERL5LIB appropriately so that Perl can find the module.
